# how to find a value in a range in worksheet code

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a value that the user inputs in one cell, in a range of values in the same workbook. In the worksheet, the user selects a value and then I need to write a code that finds that value in the range or delivers an error message. I was directed to put this in the worksheet code.

I tried specifying the worksheet of the criteria value but that hasn't seemed to make a difference as I am still getting the same error.

```
    Range("Dcust").Offset(2, 0).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight).ClearContents
Dim shuttleNum As Range
Set shuttleNum = Range("Dsched").Offset(2, 0).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)

    Set driverSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Driver")
Dim DSnumView As Integer

DSnumView = driverSheet.Range("DSnumView").Value



'''''Here is where I get the error'''
If shuttleNum.Columns(2).Find(DSnumView, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You are not scheduled to drive this shuttle", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
Else
    Dim ctable As Range
    Set ctable = Range("CTableStart").Offset(1,0).End(xlDown).Range("CTableStart").Offset(0, 3)
End If
```

Comment: Either use `shuttleNum` or `Columns(2)` as the range you want to search

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```
Range("Dsched").Offset(2, 0).End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)
```

returns a single cell.

So basically `shuttleNum` is set to a single cell and consequently this: `shuttleNum.Columns(2)` will give you an error because there is only one column in this range.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, the folowing should help.

Let's assume you have some data which starts from cell A1 but you don't know where it ends. For example:

[image]

To get the range that contains the data, which in this case is `A1:C5`, you would need to do the following:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet Name")
Set rng = sht.Range("A1")
Set rng = sht.Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight)) 'A1:C1
Set rng = sht.Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)) 'A1:C5
```

Alternatively you can merge the last two steps into one:

```
Set rng = sht.Range(rng, rng.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
```